# Как правильно сократить дробь n/m, используя алгоритм Евклида?

Tags: python

Задача:

Сокращение дроби

Сократите дробь n/m. Используйте алгоритм Евклида.

Мой код:

```
a, b = map(int, input(). split())
if a == 0 or b == 0:
    c = a + b
if a % 2 != 0 or a % 3 != 0 or a % 5 != 0 or a % 7 != 0:
    с = 1
elif b % 2 != 0 or b % 3 != 0 or b % 5 != 0 or b % 7 != 0:
    с = 1
    print(a, b)
elif a >= b:
    c = a % b
elif a < b:
    c = b % a

x = a // c
y = b // c
print(x, y)
```

Что делать, что мой код упрощает дроби не совсем так?
То есть при вводе 16 6
он упрощает до 4 1. А надо до 8 3?

Comment: Вам надо написать свой алгоритм нахождения Наибольшего Общего Делителя или можно пользоваться уже готовым в python math?  Ещё это что:  if a == 0 or b == 0:
    c = a + b ... x = a // c  <-- ???

Comment: это не похоже на алгоритм эвклида... потому и не работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a/b = x * НОД(a, b) / y * НОД(a, b)
```

НОД(a, b) вычисляется алгоритмом Евклида

т.е.

```
import math
x, y = a // math.gcd(a, b), b // math.gcd(a, b)
```

Ну НОД можно реализовать например так:

```
def my_gcd(m, n):
    m, n = max(abs(m), abs(n)), min(abs(m), abs(n))

    while m % n != 0:
        m, n = n, m % n

    return n
```

Comment: А НОД можно найти только импортируя модули? Спасибо за Ваш ответ

Comment: Просто я могу так сделать, но это не очень правильно будет, так как импортирование мы не проходили(

Comment: можно реализовать и самому - код я показал, а у вас в примере зачем то работа с несколькими простыми множителями и все - это не универсальный метод и вообще не пойми что

Comment: Да, хорошо, спасибо

Comment: Извините, у меня в пичарм почему-то после ввода элементов, прога требует переименовать пременные в вашем коде, типа по пеп8 не подходят. В чем дело?

Comment: у меня все в порядке (в pycharm) - опять же это только ворнинги и с ними должно работать

Comment: @AndrewCool если импортировать модули то это не обязательно будет алгоритм эвклида. тут похож https://kvodo.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/NOD_Evklid_Kvodo.png